# memory managment in databases

Tags: oracle

I'm looking for any information source describes how a database like oracle manages memory

Answer (score 2):

a good place to start (and to re-read from times to times) would be the [concept guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/toc.htm). Chapter 8 of the guide describes the [Memory Architecture](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/memory.htm#i12483) of the DB.